# How to set up error-mails in Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask

My server sometimes fails and I need the server to send me logs by email when errors occurs and when the server falls.

It's a simple flask application running on ubuntu server 18.04 on EC2 AWS machine.

This code will send an Exception:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    raise Exception
    #return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want an email when Flask crashes or when your app encounters an expected exception?

Comment: If you can help me on both of them, i appreciate it :)

Comment: I recommend using some NMS for this task, ie. Nagios or Prometheus. If your Flask app fails, how do you expect it to email you the logs? It has to be some external software watching your app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python logging: email entire log file as attachment when level >= ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586383/python-logging-email-entire-log-file-as-attachment-when-level-error)